# Can I get a list of the people that have Facebook-liked my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to get a list of the UID of the people that has liked one Open Graph object (I am the admin of that object). This is to gather advanced analytics, for example, "how many people that like A like also B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) you can do an FQL query such as:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="122706168308"
```

Comment: How is the Access token included here?