# Getting the Nth user who like a page I am the admin of on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

What I would like to do is find out the userId of the Nth user to like a page.

So far I am thinking it is not going to be possible.

Have found the following

http://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=[PAGE_ID]
which seems to show some of the users but only the first 400/500

I thought it may have been possible using FQL but am thinking it is not going to be since page_id is not an indexable column.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Saying that I found the following stackoverflow question which suggests it is possible but does not provide code [Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page) , the following post which got me hopeful [Can I get a list of the people that have Facebook-liked my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546844/can-i-get-a-list-of-the-people-that-have-facebook-liked-my-page) but checking http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/ looks like that wont work

It also points to this page which also seems to point to the fact it is not possible, [Retrieve Facebook Fan Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names) (this answer seems to be the most voted [Retrieve Facebook Fan Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names/2121873#2121873)). The following post seems to say yes and no at the same time [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page) . So am I right in assuming that it is not currently possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231272073596022  I wonder if it will even give you the actual order in which the fans liked the facebook page.