# How to know your 1000th like on facebook?

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-like

This might not be a development issue, but I'll ask it anyway, maybe there's a solution with Facebook Graph API.

Basically, I want to know who the nth (1000th, 2000th) 'like' of my page was, this is to give a prize or something like that.

I've seen a lot of pages who give prizes to their fans like this, so it must be possible.

If the above isn't possible, I'm also happy to know the 5 or 10 last likes.

Any answer is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As i said before - the fact that other people are doing this does not mean that it is ok.  If facebook finds your application to violate the policy it will be closed and possibly the administrators personal account as well...

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind and do a lot more research about it. Thanks for helping. You can put it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I did not answer your question :)

Comment: No but you helped me by warning and I'll be cautious in the future.

Comment: Don't worry about it my friend :)  Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a dupe question.  Please see: [Getting the Nth user who like a page I am the admin of on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963300/getting-the-nth-user-who-like-a-page-i-am-the-admin-of-on-facebook)

Also this is a bug in the API. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231272073596022

However, with that said, **you can get to the last 500 likes** via:

`http://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=[PAGE_ID]`